# Deriving $u=g(x) \implies du = g'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

$u=g(x) \implies du = g'(x)dx$

How does this work? If I think about differentials as fractions, then I can easily see that $\frac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$ and then seperate the differentials as $du = g'(x)dx$ but this is not mathematically correct.

What is the mathematically correct way to prove $u=g(x) \implies du = g'(x)dx$

Comment: In calculus, an expression like $\frac{du}{dx}$ is usually defined and treated as an entirely abstract symbol for 'differentiation of $u$ with respect to $x$', and $du$ and $dx$ have no meaning individually. How would you define the right side of the expression in your title?

Comment: It is used in u-substition to change the integration variable from dx to du

Comment: In integration, it's also an arbitrary symbol. There is no meaningful object 'du' or 'dx'; that's part of the integral notation, just long the integral symbol itself. The result is that $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f = \int_a^b f(g) g'$, which just follows from the fact if $F'= f$, then the derivative of $F(g)$ is $F'(g) g' = f(g) g'$. (There's a minor issue with definite and indefinite integrals here, but I'm deliberately glossing over it.)

Comment: Consider  the following....Suppose that both $x^*$ and $x^{**}$ lie within the interval $I=[x-\Delta x, x+\Delta x]$, and that $g(x^{**})$ and $g(x*)$ represent the maximum and minimum value of $g(t)\mid t\in I$. 

Then
$$\frac{g(x^*)-g(x)}{\Delta x}\le g'(x)\le \frac{g(x^{**})-g(x)}{\Delta x}$$
and it follows that
$$g(x^*)-g(x)\le g'(x)\Delta x\le g(x^{**})-g(x)$$
$$\Delta u^{*}\le g'(x)\Delta x\le \Delta u^{**}$$
$$\dots$$

Comment: @anomaly ??? What you are saying is nonsense.  It is not an arbitrary symbol,  it is called a differential.  The concept is developed further in differential geometry.  Look it up.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I'm well-aware of differentials and differential forms. The OP is not, and it's an abuse of notation to claim that anything presented in an introductory calculus class (which is presumably the OP's level of math) is secretly a differential form, and infinitesimal in the sense of nonstandard analysis, etc.

Comment: I disagree.  It's like saying you can't take the square root of -1 to a child,  and then they later find out you were actually lying.

Comment: I'm not saying that forms don't exist; I'm saying that in first-year calculus dealing with Riemann integrals, the $dx, du$, etc. terms are meaningless notation. In more advanced math, using a different definition of integral and in a different context, such expressions are meaningful. That's not an accident; the notation is deliberately set up to play off that earlier meaning and definition. The $dx$ in a Riemann integral is not a priori the same $dx$ in the integral of a global section of the determinant of the cotangent bundle of a manifold, even if they're similar enough to share notation.

Comment: "There is no solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$," is true. "There is no solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ anywhere ever," is false or even meaningless. It's possible to define a symbol also called $du$ that makes the expression given in the title meaningful and valid, and it's even (not coincidentally) related to integration and calculus. If you're using $\int f(x)\, dx$ to denote a certain Riemann sum, the $dx$ is just notation. (Of course, it's perfectly possible to construct such an object that reduces to the Riemann integral under ordinary circumstances.)

Comment: If you write such a long comment, better post it as answer so that you can get point for your time.